# Скачивание картинок из интернета

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо скачать картинки из Интернета и мне нужно, чтобы скачиваемые картинки отображались на странице wpf, но после сбоев сети не все картинки отображаются. Я думаю, так как они скачиваются с сети асинхронно параллельно между собой то они блочат друг друга вместе с интерфейсом программы и больше не скачиваются.

Мой программный код такой:

кусок C#:

```
foreach (InstaSharp.Models.Media m in result.Data)
{
    var temp = new SelectedMedia()
    {
        Images = Convert(m.Images.LowResolution.Url)
    };
    RecentMedias.Add(temp);
}
```

кусок WPF, это - "Плитка" соотношением 5 х 6 изображений:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentMedias}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="5" Rows="6" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Border Width="176" Height="247"  
              Margin="20,20,0,0">
              <Grid>
                  <Image Source="{Binding    Path=Images, IsAsync=True}"/>
              </Grid>
           </Border>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Напрямую в WPF я подключать ссылки из интернета не стал так как в этом случае тоже некоторые картинки блочатся.

Comment: Ну так скачивайте картинки «вручную», и подключайте. Если у вас есть где-нибудь медленный, иногда сбоящий сервер с картинками, могу наваять пример :)

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел такое решение:

C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < RecentMedias.Count(); i++)
{
   int temp = i;
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
      DownloadInst(RecentMedias[temp]);
   });
}

public BitmapImage DownloadInst(SelectedMedia m)
{
   System.Net.WebRequest request =
                          System.Net.WebRequest.Create(m._Media.Images.LowResolution.Url);
   System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream responseStream =
                response.GetResponseStream();

   BitmapImage image = null;
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
   {
      image = new BitmapImage();
      image.BeginInit();
      image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;
      image.StreamSource = responseStream;
      image.EndInit();
      m.Images = image;
    }));
    return image;
 }
```

WPF:

```xml
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentMedias}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="5" Rows="6" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Border Width="176" Height="247"  
              Margin="20,20,0,0">
              <Grid>
                  <Image Source="{Binding    Path=Images, IsAsync=True}"/>
              </Grid>
           </Border>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Но при плохом соединении у меня интерфейс при загрузке страницы тормозит и страница с картинками долго не отображается при переходе на нее не знаю что делать.